# Aggregating multiple errors

Tags: scala

I need to write code that should try to do 2 actions:

```
def foo(): Unit {
    a()
    b()
}
```

`a()` can throw an error and I still want `b()` to happen (can be solved be simple try catch finally) the thing is that `b()` can also fail and I'd like to return some kind of aggregated exception with the description of both, what is the nicest way to implement it?

Comment: If both a and b can fail but you want to process them even in a failure situation why not use Try(a).map(b).collect(result) or something? Composition of Monads should always be the way to go. If you do not want composition just Try(a).recover(w/e) Try(b).recover(w/e). I can provide a more comprehensive response if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably know `Option`, with its subclasses `Some` and `None`. An `Option` captures the idea that the result of some operation can be empty.

Similarly, Scala has `Try`, with its subclasses `Success` and `Failure`, to capture the effect of functions throwing exceptions. You can wrap the calls to `a` and `b` in `Try` objects, which you can then manipulate using the methods available in class `Try`. For example:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def getExceptionMessage[U](t: Try[U]): Option[String] = t match {
  case Success(_) => None
  case Failure(x) => Some(x.getMessage)
}

def foo(): Unit = {
  // If a() throws an exception, aa will become a Failure, otherwise a Success
  val aa = Try(a())
  val bb = Try(b())

  val errors = List(getExceptionMessage(aa), getExceptionMessage(bb)).flatten
  if (!errors.isEmpty) throw new Exception(errors.toString)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy and nice:

```
val exc = List(Try(a), Try(b)) collect { case Failure(ex) => ex }
```

You'll get list (potentially empty) of `Throwable` as the result.